# different tables instead of rows

Tags: sql, database, optimization

I would like to know which scheme is faster?

1st scheme:
  one table users with columns: cust_id, name, surname (there are 100 000 rows)

2nd scheme:
  100 000 tables named by cust_id (in each table is only one row)

I don't ask how it should be - I know that 2nd example is not very clever - but i would like to know which one is faster to query?
Is if faster to query

```
select name from users where cust_id = 194923
-> one result: John Doe
```

or

```
select name from users_194923
-> one result: John Doe
```

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: This question is probably a better fit for http://dba.stackexchange.com (there's probably a duplicate there too?)

Comment: The second is not "*not very clever*" it's totally useless. Even if it were faster, you'd lose the performance on a lot of other places. Stop even thinking about this solution.

Comment: In fact... http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19449/one-table-with-many-rows-or-many-tables-with-a-few-rows

Comment: Just read the word 100,000 tables back to yourself and you will have your answer. Think of what your SSMS would like if you had 100,000 tables to scroll through to query the right one. Think of the possibilities for user error.

Comment: I don't want to do that. I just wondered which one is faster

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a quick exercise:

What do you think happens when the server processes a `select * from table_123456`? There is all kinds on magic that happen, but still the server needs to make sure if the table `table_123456` exists. In most database servers verifying that a table named `table_123456` exists is roughly on the same time-scale as verifying if a row with `id=123456` exists, in a well indexed table. For example, SQL Server keeps the names of the tables in a system table called `sys.tables`.

And imagine how much fun it will be to write a query that will return all users called 'Peter'. Comparing this two approaches is [wronger than wrong](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronger_than_wrong).

Answer (score 4):

`100 000 tables` really? Don't do that!

Obviously the second one is faster since you know what table it is and have only one record. But here's the catch, what if you want to search for 5 persons? How do you do that? What if you don't know where that person is stored?

Database servers are designed to store huge set of records (*not one record per table*).

If you are concerned about the searching of record, just define an index on the column you want to usually search.

Comment: I wonder why someone downvoted this. There is no sane reason to have 100K tables in a database. It could even be worse in performance for some queries. Reading from the meta-data the properties of a table would be a big issue in MySQL for example which implementation's of Information Schema may not perform well in such situation.

Comment: @ypercube this seems fine but I can't find the answer on his statement.

Comment: I didn't down vote (and I 100% agree with "Don't do that!"), but I'm not so sure I agree that the second one is obviously faster. If the table is properly indexed each query should be able to perform the exact same number of reads. Also consider that a schema with that many tables is going to produce a lot of other overhead (permission checks, column validation etc) that will likely not scale linearly and would be negligible in a normal schema. I'd just suggest not encouraging that this would be faster in any way because I strongly believe it can't possibly be.

Answer (score 1):

your question regarding the second schema is irrelevant or logic less, as you can not handle the database with 10000 tables consisting 1 record in each. you must go with schema 1 ar it is relevant and shows some logic in it.
thanks